# How to strikethrough text items in listview when checked?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, strikethrough

I'm trying to strikethrough list items when they are checked, however, there's one problem: once one item is checked, another gets striked, however, the toast messages are shown correctly for each item checked or unchecked. But I can't find the way to set the position for strikethrough function. Would be grateful for any help :)

```
OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

    ListView lv = (ListView) a;
    if (lv.isItemChecked(position)) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You checked " + values.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        TextView row = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        row.setPaintFlags(row.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

    } 
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You unchecked " + values.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        TextView row = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        row.setPaintFlags(row.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

    }
}
};
```

if TextView row = (TextView)lv.getItemAtPosition(position) is used, the application breaks down - the logcat:

1-08 16:39:30.373: E/AndroidRuntime(1934): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at com.jms.purchaseexamples.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:72)
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3285)
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-08 16:39:30.383: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see where you actually select the row that was clicked to check it? findViewById(android.R.id.text1) doesn't seem like what you want..

how about:

```
//Actually select the correct item from the listview
TextView row = (TextView)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
row.setPaintFlags(row.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: looks simple and great, but the application breaks down once the item gets checked =(

Comment: can you post the logcat output at the top? whats the error its getting

Comment: if it might help I use the following list layout: simple_list_item_multiple_choice